# Normalize column with multiline values to single value per cell

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets, I have a row that looks like the following

```
A   A1
B   "b1
     B1"
C   C1
```

where b1 and B1 are in the same cell, but are on two lines. (You can achieve this by pressing ctrl-enter) How do I convert it to the where each of the items in column two is in their own row such as the following:

```
A   A1
B   b1
B   B1
C   C1
```

I'm looking to create some sort of function that I can apply enmass to a large spreadsheet and so doing it manually doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
=transpose(
   split(
     concatenate(
       arrayformula(
         split(A1:A3, char(10)) & "|")
     ),
   "|")
 )
```

Explanation: Unwrapping from the inside, first apply a split by `char(10)` (newline) to every source cell. That yields a 2-dimensional array, which needs to be serialized back into one dimension. That is done by a combination of concatenate() with another split(), and finally a transpose() to put it back to vertical.

[image]

Comment: What a genius answer. Bravo.

Comment: This works great for just one column, but it there are multiple columns, only the affect column is shift thus throwing off the different rows.

Comment: Well you did not mention in your question that there were multiple columns, and in your example and wording you spoke only about a single one. For multiple columns at the same time, there are several solutions possible depending on how exactly you need it (e.g. do you need to maintain the relationship between multiline values in the same row?)  A custom script function might be your best solution. Try to develop something yourself and post another question with more precise wording and examples if you still need help.